# Resgatar valores de um array quando o valor for maior que x

Tags: php, array

Tenho um array que diz, qual vendedor e quantas vendas ele fez:

```
array{
'a'=> 1
'b'=> 2
'c'=> 16
'd'=> 4
..
}
```

Preciso saber quantos vendedores venderam mais do 4 produtos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode percorrer o array verificando ocorrências de número de vendas maior que 4. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

$vendedores = array(
    'a'=> 1,
    'b'=> 2,
    'c'=> 16,
    'd'=> 4);

$count = 0;

foreach($vendedores as $v){
    if($v > 4) $count++;
}

echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função `map` percorrendo o array e verificando se a quantidade é maior ou igual a 4:

Pode utilizar com array de objetos, ou ate mesmo em array so de números verificando qual são os números maiores ou igual a 4

```js
var array = [
{vendedor: 'Joao', quantidade: 1},
{vendedor: 'maria', quantidade: 5},
{vendedor: 'jose', quantidade: 3},
{vendedor: 'claudio', quantidade: 7},
{vendedor: 'Joana', quantidade: 2}
]


array.map(item => {
  if(item.quantidade >= 4) 
    console.log(item)
})

var array2 = [1, 4, 5 , 10, 21, 3, 0, 3, 2];

array2.map(item => {
  if(item >= 4) 
    console.log(item)
})
```